# How to execute some instructions on selected nodes in a cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I don't have any RDD to use, I just want to execute some of my own functions on **some** nodes of my cluster, with Apache Spark. So I don't have any data to distribute, but only code (**which depends on the node that is executing it**).

Is it possible ? Is Spark compatible with this goal ?

Comment: What is your code going to do, without data? I'm currently at a loss why you would want to use Spark for something that doesn't involve data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

I *think* it is possible and I've been asked about it few times already (so had time to think about it :))

> Is Spark compatible with this goal?

The way Spark could handle it is to launch as many executors as you want to use nodes for the distributed work. That's the job of a cluster manager to spread the work across a cluster of nodes and so Spark can only use what nodes are given.

With the nodes assigned you simply execute a computation on fake dataset to build a RDD on top of.

If the computation runs on a node that should not be used, you can `hostname` inside the code and see what node you are on and decide on whether to continue or stop.

You could even read the code to execute from a database (seen a solution like this already).